# Looking for resources on these topics from Linear Algebra

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation, online-resources

I am looking for

**Characteristic roots and characteristic vectors of a linear transformation or of a matrix, Algebraic and
Geometric multiplicity of a characteristic value, Cayley-Hamilton theorem, Diagonalizable operators and
matrices. Minimal polynomial of a linear operator (matrix).**

Thanks

Comment: *Linear Algebra* by K. Hoffman and R. Kunze is a nice classic in the field.

Comment: Yes i have it .Can you tell me from which chapters are these topics taken from ?

Comment: Chaper 6, *Elementary Canonical Forms*. The book gives several (3, I think) proofs of the Cayley Hamilton theorem. If I recall correctly, two can be found in chapter 6, and the third is a corollary of the Cyclic Decomposition theorem, which is proven in chapter seven. It requires some other topics which you did not mention, but it is slightly stronger than the usual statement of the C-H theorem.

Comment: @Reveillark What about other topics .These are only topics i wish to cover

Comment: @Reveillark i have just seen Linear Algebra by Sheldon covers these

Comment: The first proof of the C-H theorem given in the book uses only concepts you've named, plus some basic things about determinants, but you should know (or be willing to learn) about those since it is a prerequisite for C-H. What I meant was, that if you wanted, for whatever reason, to read the proof of the stronger result given on chapter 7, you should also read the first pages of chapter 7 up to said proof, which isn't too long except for the proof of the Cyclic Decomposition theorem.

Comment: If you are referring to *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Sheldon Axler, I have not read that book, but I have heard good reviews. If I'm not mistaken, he manages to avoid determinants and matrices throughout the whole book up to the very end, but be advised that this is not the standard treatment.

Comment: @Reveillark Thanks for help.Others topics were Vector spaces,Lt etc i missed them because i found them in chapter2 and 3 of Hoffman Kunze